# Traditional utility outbuildings and annexes: etymology, patterns, and geogrpaphical differences

Tags: этимология

When we are talking about utility buildings near or around traditional Russian dwelling (be it *izba* or *khata*), mayhaps the first that comes to mind is the **сени** (*seni*) — enclosed veranda separating entrance from the porch.

Recently I had learned another word describing similar structure in the North of European part of Russia (Arkhangelsk region *etc.*) — **поветь** (*povet’*; variants: *повет* (*povet*), *поветье* (*povet’je*), *поветка* (*povetka*) and others). It is an annexe in the back of the house that is used not only as tool, farm implement, firewood and provision storage, but would also contain livestock (say, a cow and few hens), and even the loo, so that in harshest of winters inhabitants of the house would not even have to leave it for days.

Curious, and doing some research on the topic, I came up with several questions:

- Etymology of the first word is fairly clear: “сень” (*sen’*) is archaic equivalent of modern “тень” (*ten’* — shadow, shade), and in general sense as “cover, shelter”, according to Vasmer, and other dictionaries. But why specifically in plural form? Also, the form **сенцы** — is it purely diminutive, or does it correspond etymologically (*i.e.*, would one use this form with regular, non-building-related *сени* and other similar words)?
- Historically, *seni* initially appeared in contemporary form (canopy over the porch → open veranda → enclosed/windowed veranda) or as a simple shed/tambour?
- *Поветь* is more complicated. Vasmer is not clear:

  > По мнению Миклошича, от ве́ять (зерно). Иначе (из *ро-(v)ětь, родственного слав. jаtа) объясняет это слово Мошинский.

  Taking into account that other dictionaries (Dal’, Efremova) give such meanings as “canopy, shed” or even simply “roof”, can there be any connection with the word “ветвь” (branch: such as “крыша, крытая ветками” — “roof thatched with branches”)? Are there any modern theories or research?
- Several dictionaries list *повет* as synonym to *поветь*, yet they give different definition: administrative and territorial unit in Poland, Grand Duchy of Lithuania, Western Ukraine, *etc.*. For this meaning Vasmer gives different etymology:

  > Через укр. повíт из польск. роwiаt, местн. п. ед. ч. w роwiесiе – то же; см. Христиани, там же. Польск. слово связано с вита́ть.

  Now, is this related in any way?
- Is it fair to consider the two terms as essentially describing same structure in different dialects (at least, where *поветь* does mean lean-to shed)?
- What other regional terms are there for similar annexes?
- Why some other words, such as **клеть** (*klet’*), **чулан** (*chulan*) и **кладовая** (*kladovaja*), are more flexible in usage and can mean separate room, separate outbuilding or a lean-to, or even a partition within other outbuilding or an annexe?

---

Когда мы говорим о служебных строениях возле или вокруг традиционного русского жилища (будь то изба или хата), возможно, первое, что приходит в голову, — **сени** (закрытая веранда, отделяющая вход от крыльца).

Недавно я узнал другое слово, описывающее подобную структуру на севере европейской части России (Архангельская область и др.), — **поветь** (варианты: *повет*, *поветье*, *поветка* и др.). Это пристройка сзади дома, которая не только используется как хранилище инструмента, сельскохозяйственных орудий, дров и провианта, но и содержит домашний скот (скажем, корову и несколько куриц) и даже уборную, так, что даже в самые суровые зимы жильцы могли бы сидеть дома безвылазно целыми днями.

Заинтересовавшись и проведя некоторые исследования, у меня возникли следующие вопросы:

- Этимология первого слова достаточно ясна: «сень» — это архаический эквивалент современного «тень» и в общем смысле как «покров, укрытие» согласно Фасмеру и другим словарям. Но почему именно в форме множественного числа? Также, форма **сенцы** — это чисто уменьшительное, или оно этимологически связано (т. е., могла ли эта форма быть использована с «обычными», нестроительными *сенями* и другими подобными словами)?
- Исторически сени изначально появились в современной форме (навес над крыльцом → открытая веранда → закрытая/застеклённая веранда) или как простой сарай-тамбур?
- Со *поветью* сложнее. По Фасмеру неясно:

  > По мнению Миклошича, от ве́ять (зерно). Иначе (из *ро-(v)ětь, родственного слав. jаtа) объясняет это слово Мошинский.

  Учитывая, что другие словари (Даль, Ефремова) дают значения как навес или даже просто крыша, может ли быть какая-либо связь со словом «ветвь» (скажем, «крыша, крытая ветками»)? Есть ли какие-либо современные теории или исследования?
- Несколько словарей именуют *повет* как синоним слова *поветь*, но при этом они дают другое определение: административно-территориальная единица в Польше, Великом княжестве Литовском, на Зап. Украине и т. д. Для этого значения Фасмер даёт другую этимологию:

  > Через укр. повíт из польск. роwiаt, местн. п. ед. ч. w роwiесiе – то же; см. Христиани, там же. Польск. слово связано с вита́ть.

  Это как-то связано?
- Разумно ли рассматривать эти два термина как по-существу описывающие одну и туже структуру в разных диалектах (по крайней мере, где *поветь* означает пристройку или сарай)?
- Какие другие региональные термины существуют для подобных пристроек?
- Почему некоторые другие слова, такие как **клеть**, **чулан** и **кладовая**, более гибкие в использовании и могут означать отдельную комнату, отдельное строение или пристройку или даже отделение в другом строении или пристройке?

Answer (score 3):

В литературном и разговорном украинском языке тоже есть слово `повітка`, точно соответствует русскому `повѣтка`, слово до сих пор широко употребляется. Моя бабушка так называла капитальную постройку во дворе, в одной половине её держали коз, в другой хранили уголь, дрова, сено, огородный инвентарь. Кстати, "Етимологічний словник української мови в 7 т." тоже склонен к тому, чтобы выводить это слово от `*роvětiti` - "покрыть ветками". Смотрите [том 4, стр. 469](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.djvu).